# Rendering issue. No image

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

[![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][2]][2]Ok, so im currently in a crap house. Can anyone explain why all of a sudden my scene no longer renders properly. It was doing just fine up until last night.. When i rendered a scene it sometimes gives me a black image and other times no image at all. Even when i go back to scenes that rendered successfully before. I get nothing now. Any ideas??
[image]

Comment: Welcome, Mugen. This looks like a missing texture issue.

Comment: Hey thanks @LeoNas 
Im aware of the textures, the issue im having is with rendering. Its just not rendering at all. im going either no image results or blank images.

Comment: Heres a video of what i mean

https://youtu.be/aHCNvBM5u-M

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up Reason 2

Answer (score 1):

So i figured out what my issue was. First problem was that, (some how) my compositor nodes came undone. After i fixed that i was my image but it was in black in white, so i had to adjust from RGBA to RGB in the output section of the render tab. Now everything is back to normal.